# Advantage of declaring and instantiating variables in java GUI constructor

Tags: java, user-interface, constructor, declaration, instantiation

What is the advantage of declaring + instantiating variables in the constructor, instead of declaring outside and just instantiate in the constructor, or even declaring + instantiation both of them outside?

```
public class GUIview extends JFrame {
   public GUIview() {
       JPanel pan = new JPanel();
       JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
    }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       GUIview view = new GUIview();
       view.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

or

```
public class GUIview extends JFrame {

   JPanel pan;
   JSplitPane splitPane;

   public GUIview() {
       pan = new JPanel();
       splitPane = new JSplitPane();
    }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       GUIview view = new GUIview();
       view.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, for one, the variables declared in the constructor like that immediately go out of scope to be garbage collected...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the code was shortened in order to be postable here. But I also assume that one important part was omitted - namely that the compoents are added to the frame or other containers:

```
public GUIview() {
    JPanel pan = new JPanel();
    JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();

    // This was omitted
    pan.add(splitPane);
    this.add(pan);
}
```

If this is correct, then a general statement could be: The advantage of declaring the variables in the constructor is that your class is not messed up with unnecessary fields!

And that's important: You should NOT store GUI components as fields in your GUI class, unless you need access to them. For example:

```
class GUI extends JPanel
{
    // This component has to be stored as a field, because
    // it is needed for the "getText" method below
    private JTextField textField;

    public GUI()
    {

        // This component will just be added to this panel,
        // and you don't need a reference to this later. 
        // So it should ONLY be declared here, locally
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter some text:");
        add(label);

        textField = new JTextField();
        add(textField);
    }

    public String getText()
    {
        return textField.getText();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no special rule for exactly Java user interface here.

Fields are normally used if the variable must be accessed from the multiple methods, or its value must be retained between the calls (well, constructor is only called once so this is not the case).

If the variable is only accessed in one method and its value is no longer required after this method returns, there is no sense to declare such a variable as a field.